# What would be the opposite of exec() in Python3?

Tags: python, string, expression, exec, repr

I am trying to print the string representations of a list of expressions a long with their evaluations.

**Input**

```
def info():
    return [
    __name__,
    type(__name__),
    inspect.currentframe(),
    inspect.getframeinfo(inspect.currentframe())
    ]


#my attempt 
for a in map(str, info()):
    print("{}: {}\n".format(str(a), a))
```

**Output**

```
__main__: __main__

<class 'str'>: <class 'str'>

<frame object at 0x0ED881C0>: <frame object at 0x0ED881C0>

Traceback(filename='<ipython-input-23-1812d70522a0>', lineno=7,function='info', code_context=['    inspect.getframeinfo(inspect.currentframe())]\n'], index=0): Traceback(filename='<ipython-input-23-1812d70522a0>', lineno=7, function='info', code_context=['    inspect.getframeinfo(inspect.currentframe())]\n'], index=0)
```

**Intended Result**

```
__name__:  __main__

type(__name__):  <class 'str'>

inspect.currentframe(): <frame object at 0x0ED881C0>

inspect.getframeinfo(inspect.currentframe(): Traceback(filename='.......
```

Is there way to do what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes that the source code is in a file, and not being run in the python console, otherwise it will not work.

You can use `inspect.getsourcelines()` to do what you want:

```
import inspect

def info():
    return [
    __name__,
    type(__name__),
    inspect.currentframe(),
    inspect.getframeinfo(inspect.currentframe())
    ]

lines = inspect.getsourcelines(info)

# This removes the undesired def info() and following line
lines = lines[0][2:]

i = 0
for a in map(str, info()):
    print("{}: {}\n".format(lines[i].replace('\n', ''), a))
    i += 1
```

Output:

```
__name__,: __main__

type(__name__),: <class 'str'>

inspect.currentframe(),: <frame object at 0x00000000013C7758>

inspect.getframeinfo(inspect.currentframe()): Traceback(filename='C:/Users/czimmerman/PycharmProjects/census_data/data/test.py', lineno=8, function='info', code_context=['    inspect.getframeinfo(inspect.currentframe())\n'], index=0)
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. Console is what I was going for, and I think it may not be possible without using live code inspection. I bet if I looked at how inspect works in its source would help.

Answer (score -1):

There's possibly a convoluted way to do it using some code inspection or the traceback module. But even if you make it work it won't generalize well and it's possible it won't work with all python distributions.

Right before you try to add any expression to a list, python will evaluate that expression. So you can't really get the expression back without a hack. What you **can** do, though, is store the expressions strings in a list and execute them with `exec`. So your code becomes way easier to write.

So make sure you absolutely need this. Cause if you do, then this is way more complicated than it looks

Comment: Not sure why the downvote. Of course @chrisz solved for the toy example but if you want something more general then good luck my friend

Comment: I didn't downvote, and I'm not sure why anyone would either other than that it's not a solution. But it's an answer and a reasonable one. I agree what I am trying to accomplish may not have any justifiable purpose. I was interested in it as a lazy way to create debugging output where I could visually pair what I had written in code with the expression, but that's probably handled by inspect or traceback